# is there any app framework supported image gallery slider, intels-app-framework-ui

Tags: cordova, appframework, jqmobi

Is there any app framework supported image gallery slider.

I am using intels-app-framework-ui for front-end. I used to integrate in phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a third party image slider like http://bxslider.com/ to add image gallery slider into appframework UI

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using an App Framework plugin called [Carousel](https://github.com/01org/appframeworkPlugins/tree/master/af-carousel), which has the basic functionality of a slider with circular behavior, and it's "native" for AF-UI.

There is also [Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/), which is a more complex slider from iDangero.us, but for mobile web sites in general.